# customize amazons SES - remove amazonses.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I finally got SES to work, but now im confronted with another problem
The email sent leaves `amazonses.com` in the **from** and **mailed-by** fields like this
I am currently on sandbox access

```
from:    name@myDomain.com via amazonses.com 
to:  john@aol.com
date:    Sat, Jun 2, 2012 at 3:30 PM
subject:     Subject message
mailed-by:   amazonses.com
```

**question**: how can i remove `amazonses.com` from these 2 fileds and replace the 'mailed-by' field with my companies email address?

heres my php

```
function sendMail($to, $subject, $message, $from ) {
    require_once('sdk-1.5.6.2/sdk.class.php');
    
    $AWS_KEY = "********************";
    $AWS_SECRET_KEY = "****************************************";

    $amazonSes = new AmazonSES(array( "key" => $AWS_KEY, "secret" => $AWS_SECRET_KEY ));
    
    $response = $amazonSes->send_email(
        $from,
        array('ToAddresses' => array($to)),
        array(
            'Subject.Data' => $subject,
            'Body.Html.Data' => $message,
        )
    );

    if (!$response->isOK()) {
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
sendMail('john@aol.com', "Body message", "Subject message", "name@myDomain.com" );
```

Comment: one caveat - sent mail could be from verified domain, but if you also have the from email set up separately in amazon SES - the DKIM settings have to be enabled for it separately even if it is from the same domain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since [july 2012](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/07/17/easily-dkim-sign-your-emails-with-amazon-ses/) it is easy to sign outgoing mail via SES itself.

[Instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/easy-dkim.html) are easy and straightforward.

p.s.: sorry for nekroposting, but this question is the one that popped up when I tried to do the same thing.

Comment: necroposting is encouraged. There's even [a silver badge for it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer).

Comment: and i have got it for this answer, btw.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting this is by default you're encouraged to use Amazon's own [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) setup.

In order to remove the 'via amazonses.com' text you'll need to follow instructions [similar to these](http://br0sk.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/dkim-email-delivery-using-amazon-ses.html) in order to set up your own DKIM keys.

Note that I haven't yet tested this myself.

Answer (score 2):

Set the **MX** and **SPF** record obtained form amazon ses into your subdomain through which your sending your emails.

eg:
Suppose verified domain on amazon ses is: **domain.com**
then add the **MX** and **SPF** record obtained when you click on verfied domain to the subdomain-  **abc.domain.com**

It will change your mailed by to **abc.domain.com**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. SES allows only to send from your domain (or other verified address), and it always has the ses stamp.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your php mail has From address other than the verified email from SES it will go through the SES but via amazonses will show. But if the From address is the verified email with SES then the via address will not show up. So not to show the via address its better to change the php script of sending mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `mailed-by` with your companie's email address. To do that, you must create a `custom MAIL FROM domain` which is the domain with subdomain like `sub.example.com`.

The below is how you create the custom MAIL FROM domain `sub.example.com`.

Click on the domain `example.com`.

[image]

---

Then, the detail is shown.

[image]

---

Then, click on `MAIL FROM Domain` to show `Set MAIL FROM Domain` button.

[image]

---

Then, clicking on `Set MAIL FROM Domain` button, the window is open.

[image]

---

Then, put the subdomain "sub" to the field and click on `Set MAIL FROM Domain` button.

[image]

---

Then, the `MX Record` and `SPF Record` are shown. You must add the `MX Record` and `SPF Record` to `Route 53` in addition to the records of the domain `example.com` to verify the custom MAIL FROM domain `sub.example.com`.

[image]

---

Finally, check if the custom MAIL FROM domain `sub.example.com` is verified under `MAIL FROM domain` section.

[image]

---

If `MAIL FROM domain status` is still `pending verification`, click on `retry` in blue.

[image]

---

Then, it will be verified.

[image]

---

After the custom MAIL FROM domain is verified, `mailed-by` is  `sub.example.com` whether or not you send emails using `example.com` or `sub.example.com` and whether or not your account is in the sandbox.