# Remove "via" from SES emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail, amazon-ses, dkim, spf

When sending emails from Amazon SES, gmail shows "sent via amazonses.com".  How do I remove this?

According to Google,

> I'm a sender and I don't want my recipients to see the "via" link. What can I do?  
>
>
> Gmail checks whether emails are correctly authenticated. If your messages are sent by a bulk mailing vendor or by third-party affiliates, please publish an SPF record2 that includes the IPs of the vendor or affiliates which send your messages and sign your messages with a DKIM3 signature that is associated with your domain.

I have added both SPF and DKIM records.  When looking at the original email, it shows both passed.

> Received-SPF: pass
> Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass ...; dkim=pass ...

Any ideas?

**Answer:**
Great step by step answer posted here [Remove via from SES emails](https://serverfault.com/questions/462664/remove-via-from-emails-sent-to-gmail-from-amazon-ses)

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866971/customize-amazons-ses-remove-amazonses-com